# Correct view controller to deal with picture from UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

On the home vc, there is a button that allows the user to select a picture. I'm wondering the better approach for when the button method is called.

Option A: Present ImagePickerController modally on the root view controller, acquire picture, and push a new view controller that deals with the picture.

Option B: Push a new vc, add ImagePicker modally onto 2nd view controller, acquire picture, and deal with the picture on that same view controller.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing in "deal with the picture".  Are you just adding it?  Or is there some manipulation?

Comment: Manipulation: specifically, the user will add several nodes to the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following B if you have any substantive work to do with the picture before returning to the root.   For two reasons:

1. It reduces specific code in the root Controller
2. If you need to do this someplace else eventually, it will be easier to reuse

Also, I would suggest having the root register itself as a delegate of the new VC  and have the new VC call a delegate method when finished. It is normally the best pattern for controller reuse in a case like this.