# Unable to force device to change UIOrientation

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a vc that modally adds an image picker controller, and then goes back to that same vc when pic is selected. After I obtain the image via PickerController, I add the image to the screen, and I want the device to automatically change to landscape if the pic is landscape, and portrait if the pic is portrait.

I have unsuccessfully tried both of these approaches to force the device into landscape

```
1. 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

2. 
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]; 

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

if (!isPortrait) //isPortrait is false when pic is landscape
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}
```

Alternatively, I'm wondering if it's best to just instantiate a separate vc for the picture. I've avoided it so far after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997238/correct-view-controller-to-deal-with-picture-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you have to call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:` inside the `viewWillAppear:` method of the ViewController presenting the `UIImagePickerController`.

For that you need to know first the image orientation, you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(myOrientation>0)
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = myOrientation;
}

- (void)presentPicker {
    UIImagePickerController* imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    if(image.size.width>image.size.height)
        myOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    else
        myOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also, don't forget to set the initial and supported interface orientations in the plist (the first of the supported orientations has to be equal to the initial orientation)